# How large could an introvert be?

Tags: creature-design, anatomy

An introvert, in zoology, refers to a head or other structure where the outer layer can flip inside out and retract

What is the maximum size (in absolute terms) that such a structure realistically could attain? Specifically, I'd like to know about this structure existing as a head, with a brain, sense organs, and a mouth. I don't have any criteria for what the rest of the anatomy should be, besides that it must be able to realistically exist at its size alongside the introvert. The creature should also be terrestrial, in roughly earth-like conditions

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Working out the largest possible size that a structure will work at serves as a good generalization of asking if the structure would work at a given size. That is the worldbuilding issue that this question is for

Comment: @PostlimFort In absolute terms

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I've edited the question

Comment: will it be subject to evolution? or is it a creation in a lab/by a god.

Comment: @PostlimFort It would be evolved

Comment: Source with some explanation, https://invertzoology.wordpress.com/tag/introvert/ and a source with the obvious vertebrate example https://fineartamerica.com/featured/im-not-antisocial-funny-introvert-turtles-animals-aquamarine-marine-life-turquoise-gift-thomas-larch.html

Comment: i am not really clear on the definition of introvert - would the small mouth of the Alien be one - in that case would a human tongue (stuck out) be one?? or does it need to be 'blown out' like a inside-out latex glove that you blow into to right it?

Comment: @bukwyrm It has to go inside out fully when retracted

Comment: Is there a reason you believe an introvert would be any more size limited than other kinds of creatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest turtle like creature I can think of is the Carbonemys. It must have had a neck of about 1 meter long and 20 to 30 cm thick. It probably represents the largest introvert in a tortoise like creature. As it lived among the largest land animals known to date. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonemys

I can imagine some kind of weird giraffe like creature with a telescopic neck. Using air sacks to unfurl the neck. (1) This way it may be able to reach the leaves and fruits in tall trees. I don't deem such an animal likely to have evolved. But sometimes weird things might just work. If it would work then i'd guess a size like the neck of a giraffe or maybe a little larger may be the limit. About 2 to 2.5 meters long. Giraffes need to not exist for this creature to be able to evolve!

(1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qevIIQHrJZg Not my video. But it shows what I am thinking about with an inflating air sack.